# each. do switching between 2 different classes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

On my index page i'm calling <%= render @posts %> and want to achieve a timeline. For that i set up a Layout with every other post to be on another side (left - right).

in my posts/_post.html.erb:

the left side

```
 <ul class="timeline">       
   <!-- The Left Side-->
   <li><%= post.title%></li>
 </ul>
```

and the right site

```
 <ul class="timeline">       
   <!-- The Right Side-->
   <li class="timeline-inverted"><%= post.title%></li>
 </ul>
```

What i need is, that rails switches between those two, and uses the above code for the first post, and the below for the next ... etc etc etc.

How can i achieve this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try [`cycle`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/TextHelper.html#method-i-cycle) helper method available in rails.

Here is what you can try:

```
<% @posts.each do |post| %>
 <ul class="timeline">
   <li class="<%= cycle("", "timeline-inverted") -%>"><%= post.title%></li>
 </ul>
<% end %>
```

This should generate `class="timeline-inverted"` on even posts, i.e: 2,4 etc..